# addEventListener load fires twice on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I use this simple script loader to dynamically load Javascript after the main CSS is loaded.
Browsers like Safari/Chrome work perfectly and load the scripts once.

But Firefox fires the event twice which causes the page to not work properly.

How can I prevent this?

```js
var Loader = function () {};

Loader.prototype = {
    require: function (scripts, delay, id, callback) {
        this.loadCount = 0;
        this.totalRequired = scripts.length;
        this.callback = callback;

        var self = this;

        this.timerID = window.setTimeout(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
                self.writeScript(scripts[i], id[i]);
            }
            window.clearTimeout(self.timerID);
        }, delay);
    },
    loaded: function (evt) {
        this.loadCount++;

        if (this.loadCount === this.totalRequired && typeof this.callback == 'function') {
            this.callback.call();
        }
    },
    writeScript: function (src, id) {
        var self = this;
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.defer = true;
        s.id = id;
        s.src = src;

        s.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
            self.loaded(e);
        }, false);

        document.body.appendChild(s);
    }
};

function initJS(vendor, js) {
    var vendor_loader = new Loader();
    vendor_loader.require(vendor,
        0,
        ['js1'],
        function () {
            var js_loader = new Loader();
            js_loader.require(js, 500, ['js2', 'js3', 'js4']);
        });
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/styles/screen.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all';initJS(['/dist/scripts/vendor.js'],['/dist/scripts/main.js', '/dist/scripts/addons.js', '/dist/scripts/recaptcha.js']);">
</head>
```

Comment: I think it's the `onload` of the `link` that's firing twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `this.media` causes the `link` tag to reload, so you get two calls to the `onload`.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=f6dc2e55f461" onload="this.media='all';console.log('hello')">
</head>
```

Compare that with:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=f6dc2e55f461" onload="console.log('hello')">
</head>
```

So, I guess, change the `media` attribute from `print` to `all` and don't set the media value on load.